# How to add new folder in pycharm?

Tags: python-3.x, django, directory, pycharm, new-operator

I am practicing django on pycharm , I want to add new folder in existing project but didn't  getting any option to add new folder, how can I add?

How to add new folder

Answer (score 0):

To add a new folder to your Django project in PyCharm, you can follow these steps:

Open the project in PyCharm and go to the Project panel on the left-hand side of the screen.
Right-click on the parent folder where you want to add the new folder (e.g. the root folder of your project), and select "New" -> "Directory".
Enter a name for the new folder in the dialog box that appears, and click "OK".
Alternatively, you can also add a new folder using the keyboard shortcut "Ctrl + Alt + Insert" on Windows or "Command + N" on Mac, then selecting "Directory" from the options.

Once you have created the new folder, you can add new files or subfolders to it as needed. Keep in mind that in Django, it is important to follow the recommended directory structure to ensure that your code is organized and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Go to PyCharm and go to the directory you want to create your folder then right click on the directory or the sub-folder that you want to create folder in it and select new>directory and write the name of the folder and then press ok.